# incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[5]' from type 'char *'

Tags: c

```
char types[5];
        switch(buffer[9]){
            case 1:
                types = "ICMP";
                break;
```

error:

```
 incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[5]' from type 'char *'
```

how would I fix this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fix it without changing its type.

Array values are not modifiable l-values. If you plan to always assign it a string literal, declare it as `const char *` instead of array:

```
const char *types;
switch(buffer[9]){
    case 1:
    types = "ICMP";
    break;
```

If you want to later change the contents of `types`, then keep it as an array and just use `strcpy()` or the safer variant `strncpy()`:

```
char types[5];
switch(buffer[9]){
    case 1:
    strncpy(types, "ICMP", sizeof(types));
    break;
```